# Image positioned below to be visible on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are two images placed one below the other, what i want to do is when you hover a mouse over the top image only the portion of the image below should be visible not the entire image to be replaced.Is this possible using jquery ?.

[image]

I am stuck on where to start. I tried changing the div background on hover but i couldn't get anywhere near what i need.Thanks.

```
html

<div style="background-image: url("image1.jpg")></div>
<div style="background-image: url("image2.jpg")></div>
```

Comment: Can you paste your html part here..

Comment: Its just two divs with background images positioned one top the other using absolute positioning

Comment: no one is going to be able to help you if you dont post the code you are using.

Comment: sorry for not adding the html code as I said it only consist of two divs with position and the javascript code which i worked on is totally irrelevant to my problem hence i didn't add it in. I didn't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Think your approach to solving is wrong. Why 2 images? Why only radial Image is visible? What should be achieved exactly?

Comment: There is two images of a map. The top image of map will be with little detail about the city but as you hover over the top image of the map you can see certain details about the city that have been placed in the below image. Its radial because it will like finding clues and make the user more engaging towards finding all the details

Comment: does the circle have to move with the cursor?

Comment: @kennho Yes, it as to.

Comment: Posted an answer with jfiddle. Probably can try it and see if it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $hover = $("#hover");
  var $foreground = $("#foreground");

  $hover.hide();

  $foreground.mousemove(function(event) {
    var top = event.pageY - $hover.height() / 2;
    var left = event.pageX - $hover.width() / 2;

    $hover.css("top", top);
    $hover.css("left", left);
  });

  $foreground.mouseover(function() {
    $hover.show();
  });

  $foreground.mouseleave(function() {
    $hover.hide();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/685/

**EDIT: Updated to hide before mouse entering**
http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/686/

**EDIT:**
It doesn't really solve your problem tho if you need the background to be shown as according to your description.

Comment: Yeah, It doesn't work with images as i asked. Is it even possible to do that kinda effect ?

Comment: Hmm... sounds hard to do tho. I was thinking of placing the top layer as an element with very thick border. But it wouldn't work as well as it will be the top not being able to show instead of the background not being able to show.

Comment: one more query here, you want same image (some part of bg but fixed) to be moved along with cursor or according to the cursor position that part of the background image to be shown.?

Comment: It as to be according to the cursor position the part of the image to be shown

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged jQuery, use the jQuery .hover().

Example:

```
$("selector").hover(
  function() {
    show your hidden image functionality here
  }
);
```

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of using Javascript/Jquery. CSS can do the job as below

**HTML**

```
<div class="bgdemo"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bgdemo{
     background-image: url("image1.jpg");
}

.bgdemo:hover{
         background-image: url("image2.jpg");
    }
```

and there is a typo in your HTML, style tag is not ending properly.

**edit**

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kakurala/uzynbtah/2/), Position the background according to your requirement.

**edit**

Here I found good [article](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking) seems bit complicated but worth reading..

Comment: I don't want the entire image to replaced on hover. I only want the radial section of the bottom part to be visible on hover

Comment: I am sorry if i wasn't clear enough,  what i want is the circle to move along with the cursor. Is it possible to dynamically clip the object along with the mouse cursor